# Why macro and function having same name works only when macro is defined after function defintion?

Tags: c, function, macros

The below code works fine

```
void a()
{
    printf("In fn");
}

#define a() printf("In macro")

void main()
{
    a();
}
```

O/p In macro

But look at this code when macro is defined before the funcn definition.(Throws compilation error)

```
#define a() printf("In macro")

void a()
{
    printf("In fn");
}


void main()
{
    a();
}
```

My question why it does work when macro definition is after function declaration and doesn't work when it is before it....

Comment: Of course it fails to compile.  The macro expands out *everywhere* that `a()` is used.

Comment: in your second case when the compiler encounters a() it tries to replace a() with its expansion which you have #defined and hence it fails as it is not a valid function syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case the result is:

```
void a()
{
    printf("In fn");
}

void main()
{
    printf("In macro");
}
```

And in the second:

```
void printf("In macro")
{
    printf("In fn");
}

void main()
{
    printf("In macro");
}
```

Which is obviously not c code.

Defines are replaced before compilaton.

Comment: Note that you can write the function after the macro definition if you write `void (a)(void) { printf("In fn\n"); }`. Since the token after `a` is not `(`, it cannot be a macro invocation. Note that printing operations should end with a newline in general. I  prefer the explicit `(void)` for the function definition. The latter is partly because I routinely compile using `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror …` and not using the `(void)` runs foul of `-Wold-style-definition` and/or `-Wstrict-prototypes`.